# Multidimensional array insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

For a project Im querying a Bitcoin exchange's API through JSON and Im trying to import that into a mysql Database.

A simple var_dump of the result gives me the following:

```
array (size=141)
'BTC_LTC' => 
array (size=7)
  'last' => string '0.0235' (length=6)
  'lowestAsk' => string '0.02359999' (length=10)
  'highestBid' => string '0.0235' (length=6)
  'percentChange' => string '-0.00635047' (length=11)
  'baseVolume' => string '8.60317949' (length=10)
  'quoteVolume' => string '364.54762523' (length=12)
  'isFrozen' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Therefore I created the following columns in the table `poloniex`:

Pair, Last, LowestAsk, HighestBid, PercentChange, BaseVolume, QuoteVolume, IsFrozen of which all are INT(50) except the column 'Pair' which is a VARCHAR(50).

As you can see from the structure of the data, the pair can be derived as the main key and the other components from the second array in each row.

I figured it out this far to query it into the database:

```
$stmt = $dbc->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `poloniex` (`Last`, `LowestAsk`, `HighestBid`, `PercentChange`, `BaseVolume`, `QuoteVolume`, `IsFrozen`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
foreach($ticker as $row)
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ddddddi', $row['last'], $row['lowestAsk'], $row['highestBid'], $row['percentChange'], $row['baseVolume'], $row['quoteVolume'], $row['isFrozen']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

$dbc is the database connection to the local mysqlserver.

**Question: How can I also insert Pair into the database?**

Comment: What is `Pair` supposed to be?  Are you trying to get the `BTC_LTC`?  I'm a little confused on how you are getting that value and what trouble you are having.  I can't see how it's "derived".

Comment: 1. Do you have a Primary Key on that table? 2. What is it? 3. What exactly is "Pair"? 4. Why is it not inserted along with the rest of the data?

Comment: Pair is indeed BTC_LTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `pair` is the key, try:

```
foreach($ticker as $pair => $row)
```

Then use `$pair`.  So something like:

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `poloniex`
(`Pair`, `Last`, `LowestAsk`, `HighestBid`, `PercentChange`, `BaseVolume`, `QuoteVolume`, `IsFrozen`)
VALUES(?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

foreach($ticker as $pair => $row)
{
    $stmt->bind_param('sddddddi', $pair, $row['last'], $row['lowestAsk'], $row['highestBid'], $row['percentChange'], $row['baseVolume'], $row['quoteVolume'], $row['isFrozen']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```